# Pyspark overwriting external hive table orc file changes hive table schema

Tags: pyspark, hive, orc

I have an issue that if i run pyspark code to save data to external orc file for hive table it also overwrites hive table schema. What should i do to keep original Hive schema after each overwrite?

```
spark = launch_spark('<applicaiton_name>', dynamic_allocation='false')

## Hive query string
query_string = "select * from <schema>.<table_name>"

## Spark DF
query_res_df = spark.sql(query_string)

## Temp view for select
query_res_df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_temp")

temp_df = spark.sql("select * from test_temp")

mode = "overwrite"

df.write.format("orc") \
        .mode(mode)\
        .option("path", path)\
        .saveAsTable(table_name)
```

Comment: Please share the sample data along with the expected output.

Comment: For example from scratch created hive table has column varchar(10), but after data reload it becomes varchar(1). So my question is why it is changing hive schema? Shouldn't it replace only file content?

Answer (score 0):

Solution instead of using `.saveAsTable(table_name)` can be used `.insertInto(table_name)`. This way hive table schema is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

For orc format, from [orcOptions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/orc/OrcOptions.scala) it looks like there is also this option of setting mergeShema to True or False in saveAsTable.

```
.saveAsTable(table_name, mergeSchema=False)
```